# flask mysql not null

Tags: python, mysql, flask, null

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM image where year=%s and day=%s and month=%s and       
station=%s ',(year,day,month,station))
```

I use this query for fetching all data and I bring the data from html page just below code

```
year = request.form.get('Year')
day = request.form.get('day')
month = request.form.get('Month')
station = request.form.get('Station')
```

but the problem is if I don't write the value of year, for example
year : blank day : 22 month : 5 station : Oxford
it leads to error because year is blank. so I tried to use if statement

```
if not station:
    if not year:
        if not month:
            if not day:
                  c.execute('SELECT * FROM image')
```

but I figured out that I have to make 16 if,else statement so I tried the other ways. when I don't write the station value and make it to  not null by myself 
and tried to use it to original code that I wrote above.

```
c.execute('SLECT * FROM image where year %s and day =%s and month = %s and station=%s',(year,day,month,station))
```

but I doesn't work what I expected for. I want to use that query, if null is get into that query I want to show all data values from db. 
if you help, I really appreciate it.

this is what I updated .

```
def construct_condition(field_name, field_value):
    return field_name + " = " + str(field_value) if field_value else      field_name + " like '*'"

@app.roue("/day/",methods =['GET','POST'])
def day():
    station = request.form.get('Station')
    year = request.form.get('Year')
    month = request.form.get('Month')
    day = request.form.get('Day')
    c,conn = connection()

    sql = "select * from table where ' + ' and ".join([
    construct_condition("year", year), 
    construct_condition("day", day), 
    construct_condition("month", month), 
    construct_condition("station", station)])

c.execute(sql)
datas=c.fetchall()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to construct the filter condition based on the value of field as follows:

```
def construct_condition(field_name, field_value):
    return field_name + " = " + str(field_value) if field_value else  field_name + " like '*'"

sql = "select * from table where " + " and ".join([
    construct_condition("year", year), 
    construct_condition("day", day), 
    construct_condition("month", month), 
    construct_condition("station", station)])

c.execute(sql)
```

Comment: it says pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'year like \'*\'select * from image where " + " and day like \'*\'select * from image\' at line 1') like this...

Comment: Can you update the code you use to generate the sql?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the updated code. The error `\'year like \'*\'select * from image where " + " and day like \'*\'select * from image\'` means you concatenate `select * from image` multiple times. Try to print the sql before execute it.

Comment: oh my god... What do you need more sir??? Upload all codes here??? thank you very much...